# Unity script stops working when scene is reloaded

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create an infinite runner.

My scene have a "road creator" object that is just a trigger and a script attached to my road prefab.

Every time a piece of road leaves the road creator trigger, a new piece of road is created.

Here's the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class roadGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject road;
    
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "roadGenerator"){
            Instantiate(road, new Vector3(200, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that once the player loses and the level reloads the script stops working.

Everything gets loaded properly (the trigger object and the first piece of road with the script attached) but for some reason the script doesn't get triggered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I think I'll need some more context to understand your problem:

You have a "roadGenerator" with a trigger and the Script attached + a "Road" Prefab with the Tag "roadGenerator" right?
I suppose by "realoading the level" you mean reloading the Scene with something like `SceneManager.LoadScene(...)`

It would also be good to know what you already tried out to fix it. :)

Comment: So I have an empty game object tagged “roadGenerator”. When the level loads there is a prefab of a piece of road with the script attached. The road moves and when it goes through the roadGenerator empty object the on collision exit is triggered. It all works perfectly when I first load the scene but when I reload with scenemanager.loadscene() the trigger doesn’t work anymore

Comment: I see... the only thing I could think of right now is that you might changed the `Time.TimeScale` before reloading your scene and didn't change it back to normal. For example after the player loses, you pause the game via `Time.TimeScale = 0` then reload the scene (while the TimeScale stays on 0) now your Scene reloaded but your game is still kinda paused. Other than that I don't know what the problem could be...

Comment: That's it. I had a coroutine that slowed down time for half a second and then put it back to 1 before reloading the scene. Even if the time.deltatime was back to 1 when the scene was reloaded, for some reason it would still mess with the other script.
I removed it and now everything works fine.
Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue, and I solved it by putting "Time.timeScale = 1f;" in my start function.

Comment: You should give more context and try to understand better the question. The issue appeared to be related to timing, but managed via a coroutine, so just adding that line in Start wouldn't guarantee to solve the problem.

Comment: You should give more context and try to understand better the question. The issue appeared to be related to timing, but managed via a coroutine, so just adding that line in Start wouldn't guarantee to solve the problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35455977)